# Typescript not understanding object key in 'one of type'

Tags: typescript

I have some functions like so:

**actions.ts**

```
export const addToCart = (id: string) => ({
  id,
  type: 'ADD_TO_CART',
});

export const emptyCart = () => ({
  type: 'EMPTY_CART',
});

export const removeFromCart = (id: string) => ({
  id,
  type: 'REMOVE_FROM_CART',
});

export type Action =
  | ReturnType<typeof addToCart>
  | ReturnType<typeof emptyCart>
  | ReturnType<typeof removeFromCart>;
```

**reducer.ts**

```
import { Action } from './actions';
import { State } from './state';

export default (state: State, action: Action): State => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TO_CART': {
      return [...state, action.id];
    }
    case 'EMPTY_CART': {
      return [];
    }
    case 'REMOVE_FROM_CART': {
      return state.filter(id => id !== action.id);
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

My IDE tells me the type `Action` is:

```
type Action = {
    id: string;
    type: string;
} | {
    type: string;
} | {
    id: string;
    type: string;
}
```

However, both cases of `action.id` in `reducer.ts` throw this Typescript error:

```
Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Action'.
  Property 'id' does not exist on type '{ type: string; }'.
```

What's the issue here? My type seems correct and I am using one of the object keys that exists in one of the type options.

Comment: You have a type that is the union of three subtypes. Until you narrow the type, it has to act as if it could be *any* of them, and they don't all have an `id` property. You probably want a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions)

Comment: @JaredSmith Makes sense. The code in my question comes from my React context approach (using actions and reducers like Redux). How would this be approached when using Typescript?

Comment: Just edited my comment. You probably want a discriminated union where you `switch` on the discriminant. I use it for my reducer actions all the time.

Comment: @JaredSmith Just had a look at your link and I'm not sure what my code isn't doing that the example is. Would you be able to provide an answer with an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have created a potential [discriminated union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) `Action`, but your discriminant property `type` gets widened to a `string` type - that is the reason why TS cannot find out, which union part you meant.

A simple fix is to annotate the return type of your action creator functions with [`as const`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions), so the string literal type of `type` is retained:

```
export const addToCart = (id: string) => ({
  id,
  type: 'ADD_TO_CART',
}) as const; // add `as const`

// do this for the other functions as well
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=13&ssc=13&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wIYBMsBUIDCGscAvHABQCWWAXHOlFcgOYCUZAfJQN4CwAKDhwaAGkHCYATzDB6AcgCCAEWUB9XAHk1BRQCVc88QIC%20HDKkQp0AbkGDQkEkjTxgAWzDSiJchQ6k3BT8QnDSsgoAogCyAAq4AJo6%20obGZnAWVq52Ag7g0PAu6HBQHhAAbsAAYlAQ7j7wfjT0jMzsXLwSIljGkjJycPJ6MZoAapFqVXqa0ckGRoLpmUUwOXlO8OHAcIoIMFQoZF0APnB6wDAArlDIuP0APFsQAGYZOPgNnCdnF9e3D09Xh4vFJPt9zlcbndZI9%20i8SmVKjU6p81gItnAAMowDAwbbkDDIKQAbQAuvYBI4CnAsMBnhhLgAbeAUdC4gbY9miDJ7A7Iei7fYoNj0Tl4johYSoADuVBgCAAFpQMLyUAA6LYcSXCRAWbZKVQabS6eb0bU6hGQ5BwYlqu1svHclVC5BqmiknIWkxdYQIPWDGLxJImwxmn060pWm0e8Pe0K%20-1DEbjSbTWYh%20Rh%20MR343Bg4vFq55UZnAKDULAdGhwACEpAJqtdNDYnp1cYttPpTJgtHDwkjf3z7NbcZMNiAA)

Answer (score 0):

Supplement to ford's excellent answer

From the comments on the question:

> Just had a look at your link and I'm not sure what my code isn't doing that the example is

Your problem is that you're cheating with the types in your union: you're expecting a little too much of the inference engine. You need to *explicitly* type your reducer actions using `type` or `interface` rather than (ab)using `ReturnType` and everything will be fine.:

```
type AddToCart = {
    type: 'ADD_TO_CART',
    id: string,
};

type EmptyCart = {
    type: 'EMPTY_CART'
};

type ReducerAction = AddToCart | EmptyCart;

const reducer = (state: any, action: ReducerAction) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_TO_CART': console.log(action.id); // ok!
        case 'EMPTY_CART': console.log(action.id);  // compiler error!
    }
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=17&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAggJnAKgewMIEMBOwoF4oDeAUFKVKJAFxQDkMAIvQPqIDyTqMASojQDQkyASzjUAzsExCAdgHMBAXwDcRIhWgBRALZhQGbHkKDS66jQ0BZAAqIAmh268iy1eqhcIcAK4BjCJhgfYCFkaUN4JDQsHAAfKG1dEH1gFSIfUIkoTE9ff0MACgl0YAhqdGkQPih0IJDpag9vPwDa0IBKPAA+IzIoMQB3IWAfAAsofJrg0IA6dQ7iXt6fdDFoOkYWdk4eGmp06TFkABsIaaPkWQnW6WmRNpVFsmXV2ksbe23ePYzj0-PLyZ1W5we5QAD0YKg6R0QhOmCg-kwyEwAEJjFAFM4gA)